# Better way for constrain template function for white listed types, SFINAE?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae, template-argument-deduction

I want to make a trait / interface, e.g. `is_good`, and implement my generic functions targeting its specification.

I come up with the following code, helped by some online resources regarding SFINAE.

```
template<class C>
struct is_good: std::false_type
{
};

template<>
struct is_good<A<double, 2>>: std::true_type
{
};

template<>
struct is_good<B<double, 2, 3>>: std::true_type
{
};

template<template<class> class C, class T>
using check_constraints = std::enable_if_t<C<T>::value, bool>;
}
```

My generic functions are defined like this:

```
template<class T, template<class> class C = is_good,
    typename = check_constraints<C, T>>
void compute(const T& t) {}
```

At usage

```
// works
compute(A<double,2>());
compute(B<double,2, 3>());
// should not compile.
compute(B<double,5, 6>());
```

However, it seems a bit cumbersome. And I have to prepend

```
 template<class T, template<class> class C = is_good,
          typename = check_constraints<C, T>>
```

to all my functions that I plan to genericize.

Are there better ways?

#### Update

The basic of this question is, give that I know the body of my functions work with type `A` & `B` & `C`, how can I define my functions?

For example, in other languages, perhaps you can do

```
using T = Union{A, B, C};
void compute(T t){...}
# works with A
compute(A());
# works with B
compute(B());
```

no matter how `A, B, C` looks like.

Comment: Since you have `template<class> class C = is_2d`, does it mean your functions can work with other 'traits' in addition to `is_2d`?

Comment: Could you show one usage? It is not clear what you consider 2d. Are they only A<double, 2> and B<double, 2>?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  I updated my question, hope it is a bit clearer

Comment: @Incomputable  I updated my question, hope it is a bit clearer

Comment: Easy, readable and scalable way? No. That is why concepts are being added to the language.

Answer (score 2):

Not clear in your question. But if `is_2d` has to be in all functions, why not move it to `check_constraints`? Ref: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/s9Jql-

```
template<class T>
using check_constraints = std::enable_if_t<is_2d<T>::value, bool>;

template<class T, typename = check_constraints<T>>
void compute(const T& t){
    works(t);
}
```

---

**Update**

If you just want is a list of allowed types, the following is better, since you have c++17. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/kJN7hu

```
#include<type_traits>

template<class... Types>
struct TypeContainer{
    template<class T>
    using contains = typename std::disjunction< std::is_same<T,Types>... >::type;
};

using allowed_types = TypeContainer<
    int, 
    float
>;

template<class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<allowed_types::contains<T>::value>>
void compute(const T& t);

void foo() {
    int i;
    compute(i);
    //char c; compute(c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> However, it seems a bit cumbersome. And I have to prepend
>
> `template<class T, template<class> class C = is_good,
>           typename = check_constraints<C, T>>`
>
> to all my functions that I plan to genericize.
>
> Are there better ways?

I consider C-style macros distilled evil but, for a problem like this, I suppose that a macro for that template signature can be reasonable.

Anyway, I suggest a little partial improvement.

With your actual function-style, with the deducible type (`T`) before the default template-template parameter (`C`)

```
template<class T, template<class> class C = is_good,
    typename = check_constraints<C, T>>
void compute(const T& t) {}
```

if you want explicit a template-template parameter different from the default one (`is_good`), you have to explicit both the deducible type and the template-template parameter

```
compute<B<double, 2, 3>, is_good_i_hope>(B<double, 2, 3>);
```

losing the deduction of `T` from the function argument.

But if you express the template-template parameter **before** the deducible type

```
template <template<typename> class C = is_good, typename T,
          typename = check_constraints<C, T>>
void compute (T const &)
 { }
```

you, when you want explicit a template-template parameter different from the default one, can explicit only `C`

```
compute<is_good_i_hope>(B<double, 2, 3>);
```

maintaining the deduction of `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your traits, you might simply use SFINAE:

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<is_good<T>>
compute(const T& t) {}
```

or

```
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<is_good<T>, int> = 0>
void compute(const T& t) {}
```